# How to open data uk modal on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the data-uk-modal for open a modal box its open perfect when i click on the button but i just want to open this when page load, i have tie following code

```
<button class="md-btn md-btn-success" data-uk-modal="{target:'#my_id'}">Open Dialogue</button>

<div class="uk-modal" id="my_id" >  
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <div class="uk-modal-header">
            Custom Content here
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
    <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close">Close</button>
</div>

</div>
```

This is my js code

Please tell me how can i open the diwlogure box on page load

Comment: @Deepak Goyal: I think you have to use **data-modal** instead of tihs **data-uk-modal**

Comment: @MuhammadUsman : It looks like OP is using a customized framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give the button an ID and trigger the click on page load.

HTML

```
<button class="md-btn md-btn-success" id="openmodal" data-uk-modal="{target:'#my_id'}">Open Dialogue</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#openmodal').trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: can i open this model in on-change event in dropdown ?

Answer (score 8):

```
$(function() {
    var modal = UIkit.modal("#my_id");
    modal.show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works to me using Angular 7:

**Component.ts**

```
import * as UIkit from 'uikit';
...
...
...
  ngAfterViewInit(){
   var modal = UIkit.modal("#modal-id");
   modal.show();
  }
```

Remember: to do it, you need to be declared the UIKit javascript file on your application:

**angular.json**

```
 "scripts": [
     "./node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js",
     "./node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"
 ]
```